# short well-written programs in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources

I'm an intermediate-level programmer and I've been writing the code for several years in PHP, later C#.
Now I want to learn some C++ through reading some short(let's say up to 2000 lines) well-written non-gui program sources. 
Have you got any ideas where so find something like that?
I'd prefer some kind of networking tools... I just downloaded netcat but it's 1) written in C 2) too complicated for me

Thanks

Comment: At least consider a book off the book list too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list as sometimes they can help explain C++-idioms that might not be obvious from reading sources.

Comment: Learning by exclusively reading source code does not work.

Comment: In my experience, networking is a very complicated domain.

Comment: I think learning C first is a pretty good idea. Then the step to C++ is quite easy plus you know stuff about memory management. :)

Comment: A step to C++ from C can not be called quite easy (for most of the people).

Comment: @janoliver I disagree. Good C code is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike good C++ code.

Comment: He's coming from C#.  Starting with C will just make him hate the world - C++ will give common ground, then he can work his way into C :p

Comment: @janoliver Switching from C# to a completely different language only to learn another completely different language is useless.

Comment: I must say, I don't know C#, but I don't find C and C++ to be entirely different.

Comment: @janoliver - Well written C++ code is totally different from well written C code. Well written C code is often really bad as C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend Effective C++ #3 by Scott Meyers - it's a pretty cheap textbook, and it starts with some semi-advanced topics (at least with regard to design).

The reason I think it would be good for you is that I came from a C# background primarily, and I know that while you'll be decent with object oriented design (like I was), you'll probably get hit by a lot of the gotchas in C++ still.

The book does a very good job of showing you some intermediate level examples using arrays, pointer tricks, and newer STL/TR1 components.  It'll teach you all the finnicky const correctness rules, and it'll basically cover all the areas of confusion for you.

It's not a complete program, but I don't think you'll learn anything from a complete program.  People tend to do things wrong (even professionals) or according to their own whims.  Something like this will show you enough code to get you stably on your legs, and will, more  importantly, teach you why the code is right and what the alternatives are.  This will help you remember it vividly :)

Answer (score 2):

Pick up a book first.

I would look for small, toy problems like you would find for:

- [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)
- Programming competition websites
- [Language shootouts](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/)
- Interview questions

Language shootouts are especially good because you are coming from another language, because you can see similar concepts translated.  They will be abusively optimized and may not follow the same algorithms though.

Most of all, just start coding.

Answer (score 0):

After you're done learning the basics of C++, really delving into the STL and the Boost libraries were a fantastic way for me to pick up some of the really cool stuff that C++ allows you to do. There's a hidden language in C++ that is template metaprogramming that you can easily miss if you just skim the surface of C++.